# Simple parameter pack expansion: expected ';'

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, g++4.8

In the following snippet:

```
void normalize(path& p)
{
   // do something with p
}

template<typename... T>
void normalize(T&... t)
{
     normalize(t)...;  // (L)
}
```

In my actual understanding, the line `(L)` expands to:

```
template<typename... T>
void normalize(T&... t)  // T = {t1, t2, t3}, for example
{
    normalize(t1), normalize(t2), normalize(t3);
}
```

and each one of these expressions will execute the one-parameter version of `normalize`. However, `g++` (4.8.1) throws me the following error:

```
prueba.cpp: In function 'void normalize(T& ...)':
prueba.cpp:155:17: error: expected ';' before '...' token
     normalize(t)...;
             ^
prueba.cpp:155:20: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
     normalize(t)...;
                    ^
prueba.cpp:155:20: note:         't'
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941176/variadic-template-parameter-pack-expanding-for-function-calls

Comment: @erenon It did definitely help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expansion of parameter packs is not allowed in this context. If you create a helper class `pass`, you can do the following:

```
pass{(normalize(std::forward<T>(t)), 0)...};
```

The helper class `pass` might look as follows:

```
struct pass
{
    template <typename ...Args>
    explicit pass(Args&&...) { }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand why it's neccessary the ", 0" expression

Comment: @Peregring-lk: The return type of `normalize` is `void`, but you can't pass `void` as arguments to a function/constructor. For that reason, I use the comma operator to evaluate the expressions, and get dummy values as arguments.

Comment: I've just realized it before reading your comment. Thanks anyway for confirming my suspicions!

Comment: Last thing, the use of `{}` instead of `()` is only for avoiding unsequenced evaluation, right?

Comment: With `{}` the _initializer-clauses_ are evaluated in the order in which they appear. Unfortunately, GCC up to 4.9 is still broken in this regard. Regardless, I prefer `{}` because it avoids the _most vexing parse problem_.

Comment: You can also try: `[](...){}(normalize(std::forward<T>(t)), 0)...);`. The anonymous lambda with unspecified arguments `[](...){}` seems to be able to provide the necessary expansion context without defining `pass`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to unpack your parameter pack into a function call site or tuple, like this:

```
  make_tuple(normalize(t)...);  // (L)
```

For example, the following code would compile under gcc-4.8.1:

```
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
typedef  int path;
void normalize(path& p)
{
   // do something with p
}

template<typename... T>
void normalize(T&... t)
{
  auto tp = make_tuple(normalize(t)...);  // (L)
  //do whatever you want with the components of tp ...
}

main() {}
```

Comment: yes, it's an old c/c++ syntax that still compiles with g++ 4.8.1. Didn't want the noise so used the minimum.