# C++ parameter pack expansion

Tags: c++, templates

The code below doesn't compile (see error below the code). Can you please explain why?

```
template <class F, class... Arg>
void for_each_argument(F f, Arg&&... arg)
{
   f(std::forward<Arg>(arg...));
}
int main()
{
   for_each_argument(
     [](const auto& a){std::cout<< a;}, "Aa", 3, 4);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is an error message:

> 7:4: error: expression contains unexpanded parameter pack
>   'Arg'
>
> f(std::forward(arg...));

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what this code is supposed to do, and what's actually happening, errors thrown, etc. Otherwise, people here would have to go through your code, figure it out, debug it, etc. As written, this is unfortunately off-topic as "unclear what you're asking" or "why isn't my code working."

Comment: `f(std::forward<Arg>(arg...));` => `(f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)) , ...);` if you're using `c++17`

Comment: @super worthy of an answer! It is a great answer, so that would be really cool if you answer it. If you don't, I will do it myself :D

Comment: By the way, people who tried to close this question might consider to retract their votes. I do not think this question is unclear anymore

Comment: See [variadic template parameter pack expanding for function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941176/9305398) and [C++11 variadic templates and comma-separated expressions equivalence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16011873/9305398).

Answer (score 6):

You have several issues in your code. First of, your original line

```
f(std::forward<Arg>(arg...));
```

Is not correct syntax at all - you are expanding `arg` without properly expanding `Arg` in template. Now, you can fix at least that by

```
f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
```

This would be better, but still wrong - you will call your lambda once with 3 arguments, while it only accepts one - and instead, you want to call lambda 3 times with a single argument.

There are several ways to do this. First, and the least preferred, is to call the function recursively, as other answer suggests. This prompts ugly syntax, and also adds burden on compiler for recursive template instantiation. Much better solution is to expand the argument using array trick, for example (ignoring the forward for simplicity):

```
auto lam = [&f](const auto& a) { f(a); return true;}
bool arr[] = { lam(std::forward<ARG>(arg))... };
(void)arr;
```

In C++ 17 you can use fold expression to achieve even more neat syntax:

```
(f(std::forward<ARG>(arg)), ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Expanding a parameter pack works in contexts that expect a **comma separated list**.

That is, your code:

```
f(std::forward<Arg>(arg...));
```

It attempting to expand into:

```
f( "Aa", 3, 4 );
```

And the lambda you have supplied does not support such a call.

To expand a parameter pack into multiple function calls, use a recursive function.

```
template <class F>
void for_each_argument(F f)
{
    // (No args)
}

template <class F, class FirstArg, class... MoreArgs>
void for_each_argument(F f, FirstArg&& first_arg, MoreArgs&&... more_args)
{
    f( std::forward<FirstArg>(first_arg) );
    for_each_argument( f, std::forward<MoreArgs>(more_args)... );
}
```

Comment: Hm.  R Sahu was writing something very similar and deleted their answer.  I do not know why.

Comment: @SergeyA it is.  I am certain that the code in this question is at least C++11, so I am certain that this answer would work.

Comment: @DrewDormann Variadics are C++11, so yes, this code will work. It is just archaic.